# Execute a command each time curl outputs a newline

Tags: linux, bash, curl, pipe, streaming

I'm trying to use curl to infinitely stream messages from a remote server.

I periodically receive notifications like this:

```
$ curl -s https://my-server.com/status
Backup in progress...
Backup completed.
Disk space is about to fill up.
```

I want `send_notify` to be executed **each time** curl outputs a new line.
I created the script below, but it did not work.

```bash
notify_pipe() {
    read -r msg
    notify-send "$msg"
}

# Does nothing, just a blinking cursor.
stdbuf -oL curl -s https://my-server.com/status | notify_pipe
```

Please help me understand why this is not working and how to make it work.

I'm a beginner, I would appreciate any help! (and please forgive my poor English)

Comment: Your command `notify_pipe` terminates after having read the first line. The more interesting question for me is, why _curl_ did not abort with a _broken pipe error_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the output lines in a loop:

```bash
stdbuf -oL curl -s https://my-server.com/status |
    while read line ; do
        notify-send Status "$line"
    done
```